# Intersecting nested JSON documents with jq

Tags: json, jq

I'm looking for a general approach to intersect two nested JSON-objects, in order to retrieve all common key-value pairs.

Given the following JSON-documents

```
{
    "a": 0,
    "b": [
      "ba",
      {
        "bb": {
          "bba": "a",
          "bbc": [1, 2]
        }
      },
      {
        "bc": {
          "bca": [2],
          "bcb": 5
        }
      }
    ],
    "c": 1
  }
```

and

```
 {
    "a": 1,
    "b": [
      "ba",
      {
        "bb": {
          "bba": "a",
          "bbc": [1,3]
        }
      }
    ], 
    "c": 1
  }
```

I want to find their intersection.
I expect to get the following JSON-document which only contains those key-value-pairs JSON-objects that are present in both inputs:

```
 {
    "b": [
      "ba",
      {
        "bb": {
          "bba": "a",
          "bbc": [1]
        }
      }
    ], 
    "c": 1
  }
```

I looked into jq's documentation, but could not find a hint on how to do this.
My tries to use the minus-operator were unsuccessful yielding `object ... and object cannot be subtracted`.

```
 cat obj-list.txt | jq -c '.[1] - (.[0] - .[1])'
```

Can you give me some hints on how to accomplish a intersection of nested JSON-objects with jq?

Thank you already in advance for helping me out.

*Update:*
Given that the JSON-objects do not have the exact same structure, but differ like `a = {"a": [{"aa":1]}, b = {"a": 0}` for example. I'm interested in a solution on how to add error checking to catch `Cannot index number with string`-errors and the like?

Comment: Not part of your question, but as an aside: always prefer `jq ... <obj-list.txt` or `jq ... obj-list.txt` or `<obj-list.txt jq ...` instead of `cat obj-list.txt | jq ...`. It's not a huge deal for jq in particular, but it's literally the difference between O(1) and O(n) operation for other commands (`tail`. `wc -c`, etc), and can have smaller differences for others (f/e, `sort` can parallelize its operation with a real file handle, but not with a pipe from `cat`, since multiple threads or subprocesses can read input in parallel only with a seekable file handle).

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of the UUOC! Didn't think about it here. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $a holds the contents of one of your JSON entities and $b holds the other, then the following will perform the type of intersection you describe:

```
reduce ($a|paths) as $p (null;
  ($a|getpath($p)) as $va
  | [try ($b|getpath($p)) // empty] as $vb
  | if ($vb | length > 0) and ($va == $vb[0])
    then setpath($p;$va) else . end)
```

You may however wish to explore variations of this, e.g. if there is nothing in common.

---

Footnote 1:

The above is easily adapted to similar problems.  For example, if the common structure is all that matters:

```
def structural_intersection($a;$b):
  reduce ($a|paths|select(.[-1]|type=="string")) as $p (null;
  ($a|getpath($p)) as $va
  | [try ($b|getpath($p)) // empty] as $vb
  | if ($vb | length > 0) 
    then setpath($p;null) else . end) ;
```

Footnote 2:
To handle arrays using array-intersection, you might wish to consider the following, but please be aware that in some cases, this hybrid approach will probably produce results that you might not expect:

```
def special_intersection($a;$b):
  def i(x;y): x - (x-y);
  reduce ($a|paths) as $p (null;
    ($a|getpath($p)) as $va
    | [try ($b|getpath($p)) // empty] as $vb
    | if ($vb | length > 0)
      then if ($va == $vb[0])
           then setpath($p;$va)
           elif ($va|type == "array") and ($vb[0]|type) == "array"
           then setpath($p; i($va; $vb[0]))
           else . end
      else . end) ;
```

Comment: I have an additional question: Given that the JSON entities do not have the exact same structure, but differ like `a = {"a": [{"aa":1]}, b = {"a": 0}` for example. How could I add error checking  to catch `Cannot index number with string`-errors and the like?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Jeremy - Please see update.

Comment: Unfortunately, I still have a remaining problem, that I do not get to solve on my own. 
Given `a = {"a": 0, "b": [["bb"], {"bb": 1}],"c": 1}` and `b = {"a": 0, "b": [["aa", "bb"], {"bb": 1}], "c": 1}`, how can I iterate over the array values? `["bb"]` does not get matched. Do you have a hint for me, @peak ? Thanks already in advance.

Comment: @Jeremy - See Footnote 2.

Comment: Thank you very much!! Great help.  

Fn. 2 works in most cases, however, I noticed some strange behaviour. Setting `a = {"a": ["cc", "bb", "aa"]}` and `b = {"a": ["cc", "oo", "aa"]}` yields `"a": ["cc", "aa", "aa"]}`
Does this has to do with sorting or where could be the source of this?

Comment: It is to be expected as `.a[2]` is the same in both $a and $b.  The approach taken by Fn.2 is a hybrid one, and so are the results. You might was to consider running `unique` on arrays in the result?  If you can come up with an algorithm (e.g. in Python) that meets your requirements, I'm sure it could be implemented or translated to jq.

Comment: I see, I implemented a recursive function in Python. It can be found here: https://pastebin.com/T67TDP1B 
Unfortunately, it is not as efficient as I want it to be and therefore I am looking to port it to jq somehow, which I can call via `pyjq` to gain better performance. I was reading the language specification on `jq`'s github page which was/is not enough to grasp the language good enough. If you can point me to any helpful resources, I would be thankful.

Comment: I think, I forgot to tag you in my previous comment.

Comment: @Jeremy - Re helpful resources, see the jq wiki, and i.p. the FAQ (https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ) and Language Description (linked on that page).  See also my own "Stream-Oriented Introduction" at https://github.com/pkoppstein/jq/wiki/A-Stream-oriented-Introduction-to-jq

Comment: The wiki forked from you looks very promising! Thanks for the link and again for you super helpful answers!